# WebdriverIo doesn't seem to exclude my folder containing Page Object Files

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

My wdio file contains the following code:

```
specs: [
    'tests/*.js'
],
```

*// Patterns to exclude.*

```
exclude: [
    'POM/*.js'
],
```

Exception Message: **ERROR: Cannot find module 'POM/LoginPage.js'**

Please note: Only seems to be affecting windows machine.

**My project structure:**

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hey again Sam! Any progress on this too? :)

Answer (score 0):

That's a very interesting behavior. Your tests should *run and pass as expected* in this scenario. Firstly, update your question with the following: *WebdriverIO version*, *entire stack-trace error* and *a page-object snippet*.

There is no real solution though, as this is not *an actual problem*. The `specs` & `exclude` lists should filter in/out the features you want to run. I have no idea why you would include the page-objects folder here (`POM`).

Just remove the page-objects entry from the `exclude` list. Only the `specs` feature-files will be run. You most likely are getting this error due to a different config issue.

---

**Hunch:** There was no stack-trace error line-error, but I presume you're getting it in the page-object import from the first feature-file where it is used. This would mean that the `exclude` entry has nothing to do with it.

Update your question taking my response into consideration and we'll go from there. Cheers!